# Cucumber Extent Report - How to add screenshots to each cucumber step

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, extentreports

I am unable to add a screen shot to each step I execute on to my cucumber Extent report. Please see code snippet below.

```java
public String captureScreenshotMobileWeb(WebDriver driver, String screenShotName) {
    TestLogger tLog = new TestLogger();
    String logFilename = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmsss")).format(new Date());

    try {
        Object ts;
        if (driver.equals(this.wdriver)) {
            ts = this.wdriver;
        } else {
            ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        }
        File source = (File) ((TakesScreenshot)ts).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String dest = "C:\\Users\\nb313260\\Documents\\Projects\\Servicing\\staff-servicing-automation-test\\ScreenShots\\" + screenShotName + "_" + logFilename + ".png";
        File destination = new File(dest);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        tLog.logInfo("Screenshot taken: " + screenShotName);
        return dest;
    } catch (Exception var9) {
        tLog.logError(var9.getMessage());
        return var9.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Feature:

```
    Feature: Account overview display for all product types 
Scenario Outline: As a user I must be able to view account details Given Client is authenticated 
When User launches staff servicing with Account number "<Account_Number>" for "<Product_Type>" 
Then User must be able to view account overview page and details under At a glance, Spotlight & Account information for selected "<Account_Number>" account number on screen Examples: |Account_Number|Product_Type|
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the cucumber version & extent report version you are using? can you also post  your cucumber setup - feature file, step def, etc?

Comment: Feature: Account overview display for all product types

  Scenario Outline: As a user I must be able to view account details
    Given Client is authenticated
    When User launches staff servicing with Account number "<Account_Number>" for "<Product_Type>"
    Then User must be able to view account overview page and details under At a glance, Spotlight & Account information for selected "<Account_Number>" account number on screen
    Examples:
      |Account_Number|Product_Type|

Comment: @Sureshmani I am using Cucumber Version: 182.3934 and Extent Report version: 3.0.

Comment: See the extent report 3 documentation here - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#insert-screenshots